# RXJS Angular HTTP call a HTTP request to check internet connection

Tags: javascript, rxjs

So I am using rxjs observables to call a http request every 30 seconds using interval and repeat. However, when there is not internet connection and the observable calls onError but the observable never repeats back. I am using also retryWhen and it is not working

Any suggestions?

Here is my code

```js
   Observable.interval(2500).repeat()
      .flatMap(() => this.http.get(url))
      .map(res => res.text())
      .catch(() => {
        return Observable.of('ERROR');
      })
      .retryWhen(error => error)
      .subscribe(data => {
          // tools.destroyLoadingMessage();
          alert('CONNECT OBSEVABLE ' + data);

         // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      }, err => {
        alert('DISCONNECT OBSEVABLE ' + err);
        // tools.showLoadingMessage('No inrernet');
      })
```

Comment: flatMap to Observable.ajax (or fromPromise, fromCallback etc.) do the ajax there and place catch on that one. Nothing can come from an observable once it errors

Comment: Do you have an example

Answer (score 0):

To avoid breaking observable when request fails you have to catch the error from request so the stream can continue.

When there is an error you will see `value: error` otherwise it will be server's response.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(2500)
  .flatMap(() => {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .catch(error => Rx.Observable.of('error'))
  })
  .subscribe(
    value => console.log('value: ' + value),
    err => console.log('error'),
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
```

Comment: True, it will try to retry all the time. Let me think how to implement there a delay :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosFerrel I've just noticed that you are catching the error BEFORE `retryWhen`. So you are basically making to pass correctly.

Comment: is working I put my catch after retryWhen however it never prints out the error

Comment: @JuanCarlosFerrel I think it should never print out error since you want it to repeat all the time, right?

Comment: Well I need to put some message or something

Comment: @JuanCarlosFerrel Alright in that case you need to consider errors as normal values and not to finish the stream. I have a question ... I see `repeat` operator after interval. Why it's there? Interval repeats on its own.

Comment: I thought repeat works with interval so how can I show the message and then retry?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFerrel I updated the answer. Basically you need to catch the error inside of `flatMap`.